# Jquery UI Autocomplete & Ajax multiples returns from success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am currently creating a website and I must use an API to recover all schools of higher education in France, so that when the user registers, he types in an input his university and choices are offered to him thanks to Jquery ui autocomplete.

And that's what it gives:

```js
 $('#recherche').autocomplete({
                open: function () { $('.ui-autocomplete').css('z-index', 1050);},
                source : function(requete, response){ // les deux arguments représentent les données nécessaires au plugin
                    $.ajax({
                        url : 'https://data.enseignementsup-recherche.gouv.fr/api/records/1.0/search//?dataset=fr-esr-principaux-etablissements-enseignement-superieur', // on appelle le script JSON
                        dataType : 'json', // on spécifie bien que le type de données est en JSON
                        data : {
                            q : $('#recherche').val() // on donne la chaîne de caractère tapée dans le champ de recherche
                        },

                        success : function(donnee){
                            console.log('k');
                            response($.map(donnee, function(){
                                var tab = [];
                                for(var i= 0; i < donnee["records"].length; i++)
                                {
                                    tab[i] = donnee["records"][i]["fields"]["uo_lib"];
                                }
                                console.log(tab);
                                return tab; // on retourne le tableau des écoles
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                },
      
                select : function(event, ui){ // lors de la sélection d'une proposition
                    $('#recherche').val( ui.item.desc ); // on ajoute la description de l'objet dans un bloc
                }
            });
```

```css
.ui-autocomplete {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 217px;
    z-index: 1000;
    float: left;
    display: none;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 4px 0;
    margin: 0 0 10px 25px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #ccc;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    *border-right-width: 2px;
    *border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slideReveal/1.1.2/jquery.slidereveal.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="recherche" name="school" class="center bottom-margin-10" type="text"  placeholder="Libellée établissement" >
```

Try to write "capitole" and you will see that the same result is present 3 times, I can not understand why

Comment: Or "paul sabatier"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something about `$.map()` was working weird. I switched to `$.each()` and am getting better results.

```js
$('#recherche').autocomplete({
  open: function() {
    $('.ui-autocomplete').css('z-index', 1050);
  },
  source: function(requete, response) {
    var tab = [];
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://data.enseignementsup-recherche.gouv.fr/api/records/1.0/search//?dataset=fr-esr-principaux-etablissements-enseignement-superieur',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        q: requete.term
      },
      success: function(donnee) {
        console.log('k');
        $.each(donnee.records, function(k, v) {
          tab.push(v.fields.uo_lib);
        });
        console.log(tab);
        response(tab);
      }
    });
  },

  select: function(event, ui) { // lors de la sélection d'une proposition
    $('#recherche').val(ui.item.desc); // on ajoute la description de l'objet dans un bloc
  }
});
```

```css
.ui-autocomplete {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 217px;
  z-index: 1000;
  float: left;
  display: none;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  margin: 0 0 10px 25px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  *border-right-width: 2px;
  *border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slideReveal/1.1.2/jquery.slidereveal.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="recherche" name="school" class="center bottom-margin-10" type="text" placeholder="Libellée établissement">
```

Didn't make any other changes. Also better to use dot notation when you can with objects.

Hope that helps.